# Ubuntu 14.04, HP Laptop, Docking Station, 2 External Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution

First let me describe my scenario:

I have a HP laptop that while in the office is docked in a docking station via the port on the bottom of the laptop. Connected to the docking station I have two identical monitors, one is connected via dvi while the other is connected via vga. While both monitors are connected simultaneously only one monitor is turned on at a time as one is on a standing desk while one is at a sitting desk. The laptop lid remains closed while it is docked so its screen is not used either.

Now to my problem...

As stated, the two external monitors are identical, having the same resolution etc... the laptop screen has a different resolution. Ultimately my goal is to have both external monitors hooked to the docking station and have the display settings set to duplicate as I only use one monitor at a time. However, when doing this I am forced to reduce my resolution to that of the laptop screen even though the lid is closed and it is not being used while docked. My only work around so far is to unplug the unused external monitor so that everything is display correctly on the used monitor. I switch between standing and sitting many times throughout the day and having to swap the cables is quite a pain. How can I go about configuring the display settings to duplicate the screen on both external monitors without reducing the resolution to that of the unused laptop screen?

Comment: try this command, `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output LVDS1 --off`, being VGA1 your external monitor, and LDVS1 your laptop screen.

Comment: @bistoco, Thanks for the response. Is this turning off my laptop monitor indefinitely? Will I have to issue another command when I want to use my laptop as a laptop?